# Paperclip doesn't cropping image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to add attached file to my post model

I already used paperclip, but in this case there is one strange problem, paperclip doesn't work if I set `:styles`,
when I'm trying to save, it's render message `check the problem below`, but there not mentioned any problem

this one doesn't work

```
class Post
    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

this code works good

```
class Post
    has_attached_file :photo
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `imagemagick` and `rmagick` gem for [Attachment Processing](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#custom-attachment-processors)